# How to determine if a specific set of tables in a database are empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have database A which contains a table (CoreTables) that stores a list of active tables  within database B that the organization's users are sending data to.

I would like to be able to have a set-based query that can output a list of only those tables within CoreTables that are populated with data.

Dynamically, I normally would do something like:

For each row in CoreTables
   Get the table name
   If table is empty
      Do nothing
   Else
      Print table name

Is there a way to do this without a cursor or other dynamic methods? Thanks for any assistance...

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not trying to build the list of tables in CoreTables based on the result, right? CoreTables already has a pre-populated set of tables, and you want to run a query that shows the subset of those tables that currently have at least one row?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks for all the responses. I'm still working my way through them all to be sure I understand all the points. So just to be clear on my end, there's no way to do the above without recourse to at least one system-level structure (e.g., sys.partitions)?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "do the above without recourse"... did you try any of the solutions that have been posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most efficient option is:

```
SELECT c.name 
  FROM dbo.CoreTables AS c
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.partitions 
    WHERE index_id IN (0,1) 
    AND rows > 0
    AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(c.name)
  );
```

Just note that the count in sys.sysindexes, sys.partitions and sys.dm_db_partition_stats are not guaranteed to be completely in sync due to in-flight transactions.

While you could just run this query in the context of the database, you could do this for a different database as follows (again assuming that CoreTables does not include schema in the name):

```
SELECT c.name
FROM DatabaseA.CoreTables AS c
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
    FROM DatabaseB.sys.partitions AS p
    INNER JOIN DatabaseB.sys.tables AS t
    ON p.[object_id] = t.object_id
    WHERE t.name = c.name
    AND p.rows > 0
);
```

If you need to do this for multiple databases that all contain the same schema (or at least overlapping schema that you're capturing in aggregate in a central CoreTables table), you might want to construct a view, such as:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CoreTableCounts
AS
    SELECT db = 'DatabaseB', t.name, MAX(p.rows)
      FROM DatabaseB.sys.partitions AS p
      INNER JOIN DatabaseB.sys.tables AS t
      ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
      INNER JOIN DatabaseA.dbo.CoreTables AS ct
      ON t.name = ct.name
      WHERE p.index_id IN (0,1)
      GROUP BY t.name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT db = 'DatabaseC', t.name, rows = MAX(p.rows)
      FROM DatabaseC.sys.partitions AS p
      INNER JOIN DatabaseC.sys.tables AS t
      ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
      INNER JOIN DatabaseA.dbo.CoreTables AS ct
      ON t.name = ct.name
      WHERE p.index_id IN (0,1)
      GROUP BY t.name
    -- ...
GO
```

Now your query isn't going to be quite as efficient, but doesn't need to hard-code database names as object prefixes, instead it can be:

```
SELECT name 
FROM dbo.CoreTableCounts 
WHERE db = 'DatabaseB'
AND rows > 0;
```

If that is painful to execute you could create a view for each database instead.

Comment: Also, you should be careful if you have multiple tables with the same name but with different schema. If dbo.CoreTables includes schema name, the above should be ok, otherwise you may want to consider adding it.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this query if dbo.CoreTables and the tables within are in different databases? For example, if CoreTables is in database A, and the tables referenced are in database B?

Comment: @user1417733 can you update your original question to include the cross-database requirement?

Comment: Thanks very much Aaron for all the suggestions. The multi-database query is currently not returning what I expect, so I'm debugging and will update when I see where the failure is.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can do something like:

```
SELECT o.name, st.row_count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st join
     sys.objects o
     on st.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE index_id < 2 and st.row_count > 0
```

By the way, this specifically does not use OBJECT_ID() or OBJECT_NAME() because these are evaluated in the current database.  The above code continues to work for another database, using 3-part naming.  This version also takes into account multiple partitions:

```
SELECT o.name, sum(st.row_count)
FROM <dbname>.sys.dm_db_partition_stats st join
     <dbname>.sys.objects o
     on st.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE index_id < 2
group by o.name
having sum(st.row_count) > 0
```

Comment: For a partitioned table, you'll get duplicate rows if any such table has data in more than one partition.

Comment: I don't know if SUM is the right answer either, all you need is one partition with at least one row.

Comment: Aaron, that's true, you make a very good point.  However, I often use the version (with the SUM) to get the row count for tables.  It seems easiest to build on top of that, unless he has thousands of tables which could slow down the query.

Comment: Yeah I just meant that he doesn't need the SUM because he just wants to know if it is empty (yes/no).

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
//
            foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in yourDataSet.Tables)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count != 0) { PrintYourTableName(dt.TableName); }
            }
            //
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can do it, that relies on system tables, so be AWARE it may not always work in future versions of SQL.   With that strong caveat in mind.

```
select distinct OBJECT_NAME(id) as tabName,rowcnt
from sys.sysindexes si
join sys.objects so on si.id=si.id 
where indid=1 and so.type='U'
```

You would add to the where clause the tables you are interested in and rowcnt <1

Comment: Please don't use sys.sysindexes - this is a backward compatibility view. You should be using sys.partitions or sys.dm_db_partition_stats, which are public and documented catalog views / DMVs that are much more insulated from future change.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I knew it was backward compatible, and wanted to warn the OP.   Thanks for showing the better view to use...